# trouble accessing 'some' async data in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

this is with "ember-data": "~2.11.1"

I've got a channel model which includes 'outputs'

```
outputs: DS.hasMany('output', {
    async: true
}),
```

and the output model includes 'identity'

```
channel: DS.belongsTo('channel'),
identity: DS.belongsTo('identity', {
    async: true
}),
```

in the route of the output (which is below the channel), i doing this in the model

```
model() {
    let channel = this.modelFor('channel').channel
    let outputs = channel.get('output')
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        channel: channel,
        outputs: outputs
    })
}
```

and that is letting me see all the outputs the belong to the channel, as expected.

where I am having a problem is the identities belonging to an output.

now the identities can be shared by the outputs, so for example an identity might be 'youtube' and there might be 3 outputs with the same 'youtube' identity

what I'm seeing is that the one of those outputs has the 'youtube' identity details but the other 2 outputs are seeing .get('identity') to be null.

Have i set model or model hook incorrectly? Or is it doing something to stop me from retrieving the identities again (some kind of caching?)

Comment: This is probably a problem with your server responses. Maybe you sent an empty relationship? This will be cached, yes.

Comment: server response was find. In the jsonapi response the "included" section include a single copy of each unique identities

Comment: can you show the server response? Oh, and I think its `channel.get('outputs')` not `channel.get('output')`. Is this a typo?

Comment: yes that was a typo that didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!

in the Output model i needed to add to the identity attribute :

```
inverse: null
```

to quote the [Ember Guide, Models, Relationships, Explicit Inverses](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/relationships/#toc_explicit-inverses)

> Relationships without an inverse can be indicated as such by including
>   { inverse: null }.

which is not at all clear, but Ember Data assumes there is a 1 to 1 relationship somewhere that doesn't actually exist. When Ember Data tries to keep this inverse relationship in sync it will often set other conflicting relationships to null.

To fix this you can explicitly tell Ember Data there is no inverse relationship by using inverse: null.